# COCOA NSString indexOf?

Tags: cocoa

I have a NSString *url now i need to know if another string @"iframe" is in the NSString url and use it in an if so i can handle things differently

I would like an example if statment

Comment: The people answering this question are trying to be _helpful_.

Comment: Tim how is it help full to just give some one a google page result i'm sure if some one is using this system they have used google first with no look @matei has been help full in trying to resolve the problem and he is working with me with the help he has given, to provide an answer for some one to give first link in google is daft

Comment: O and another point for that options dint do any thing so the answer he provided was incorrect and usless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
NSRange range = [url rangeOfString: @"iframe"];
if (range.location == NSNotFound) ...
```

Comment: i have looked at that but it triggered an NSExecption i'm very new to COCOA

Comment: Updated Post:: Expected expression before '{' token is triggered with your code above

Comment: Compile error:
Request for member 'location' in something not a structure or union

Sorry

Comment: anytime. my cocoa skills are a bit outdated (i didn't write a single line of obj-c in the past year or so )

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `[NSString rangeOfString:]` in the [documentation for NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).  There are other variants as well `rangeOfString:options:` which allows you to make case insensitive compares.

In your case you'll likely want something like the following:

```
NSRange range = [url rangeOfString: @"iframe"];
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception or a crash?